# Petrel's workflow editor

Tags: editor, workflow, petrel

In petrel software, can workflow editor be used to automize the use of a "process" such as "geomechanical modeling" on a series of (pre-defined) realizations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can. You have access to all processes from within workflow editor. once you insert the process of interest you can open it just like you do normally outside of the workflow interface, and then define the settings you want. Note that you can define variables in advance and use them as values inside the process.